# Rendering an image from the Unsplash API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I have extensively researched this matter both on Stack Overflow and Google but found nothing conclusive. Since I'm completely new to the concept of API usage within Rails I have to ask for some advice.

I have followed the procedure from [the github page](https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash_rb)

I have included the Unsplash helper in application_helper.rb as follows

```
def show_photo
 Unsplash::Photo.find("tAKXap853rY")
end
```

and simply added

```
<%= image_tag show_photo %>
```

in my view.

This returns an object (So connectivity is good)

```
<img src="/images/#&lt;Unsplash::Photo:0x007fc4b2f953c0&gt;" alt="#
<unsplash::photo:0x007fc4b2f953c0>">
```

I'm aware that Rails is looking for a picture in the assets/images folder

How do I parse the inbound JSON and render it in my Rails view?

Comment: try like this never used unsplush personally `<img src="<%= show_photo.urls['full']%>">`

Comment: or `<img src="<%= show_photo['urls']['full']%>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the urls key within the OpenStruct attributes in the Photo object that includes the `raw`, `full`, `regular`, `small` and `thumb` sizes, also as keys.

So, just to test you could use the `raw` one, like:

```
<%= image_tag Unsplash::Photo.find('tAKXap853rY')[:urls][:raw] %>
```

Or I think you could modify your method to accept one parameter which is the size key of the image, like:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_photo(size)
    Unsplash::Photo.find("tAKXap853rY")[:urls][size.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Then:

```
<%= show_photo('raw') %> # 'full', 'regular', etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

further to this solution I am trying to display the photographer's name by using the user.name method.
In the console I can get the following :

```
photo = Unsplash::Photo.find("tAKXap853rY")
photo.user.name
```

will return
 => "Alejandro Escamilla".

But in RAILS :

```
def show_photo(size)
 @photo =Unsplash::Photo.find("tAKXap853rY")[:urls][size.to_sym]
end
```

just trying to display the name in my view like:

```
 <%= @photo.user.name %> will return "user undefined method".
```

The .user.name is accessible in the console but not in rails! What have I missed? Thanks

Comment: this is way late for you but, its because in console you were using  Unsplash::Photo.find("tAKXap853rY") but in the second example you had added [:urls][size.to_sym]